# C code along with assembly code - debugging and knowing intermediate values

Tags: c++, c, debugging, assembly, nmake

I have a repo where code is jumping from C/CPP code to assembly code. Although I want to debug the code parts of assembly code , I am not exactly sure on how to do the same. I want to know intermediate values in the assembly code execution. Any suggestions on the same would be welcome. I don't have a solution file like setup for my repo. I use nmake to build my code and use the executable after that

Comment: Most debuggers you will come across should be able to step into assembly functions, and be able to display registers.

Comment: The bottom of https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info has some tips on debugging with GDB or Visual Studio's built-in debugger.  Use "disassembly" mode instead of source to see what's actually going on.

Comment: I know (because the runtime library sources were built this way) that it is possible to get symbols from assembly source code (including line number information) into the PDB file.  You can then step through it more easily.  *But*, I don't know how to do that, what assembler are you using?  Maybe there's a suitable command line switch.

Comment: @PeterCordes ^^

Comment: @PaulSanders: For debugging calling-convention issues, you probably *want* to see the compiler-generated asm at the call site, to see which registers the compiler is putting your args in, and how it's using the return value, and if it's depending on call-preserved registers to keep their values but your code stepped on them without save/restore.  Plus, if you're using an assembler like MASM, it can invent instructions, like turning `ret` into `leave`/`ret`.  Or other cases of MASM making the true machine instructions not obvious from the source.  Disassembly debugging is the ground truth.

Comment: @PeterCordes Fair enough.  But if you can get assembly-level source code debugging going, you can do both.

Comment: You just mentioned ```nmake```, neither which ```OS``` nor which ```compiler```. Assuming Microsoft VC++, you can see the debugging information by setting breakpoints where ever you'd like. If instead using ```MinGW```, you can use ```GDB``` to trace debugging of both C/C++ and Assembly code.

Comment: If you are using Windows/MSVC compiler, i would also suggest to try `WinDBG`, as the Visual Studio debugger sometimes can behave weird with assembly code. Also make sure you have `Debug Information Format` set to `Program Database (/Zi)`, under project properties->C/C++->General